# Ubuntu 17.04 Shutdown Logs

Tags: 17.04, error-handling, logs

My Computer (Old Dell Inspiron 5315) keeps shutting itself off randomly and I want to find the Logs as to why this is happening. I have searched here and it has said {/var/log/messages} but no file or directory exists like that on 17.04. Where can I find this information?

Comment: I downloaded and used /sensors. CPU temp is @ 25.0 C.

Comment: ubuntu has /var/log/syslog messages is in RedHat based systems. check there and in /var/log/kern.log

Comment: I looked at both of those logs and it doesn't have any "lay-person readable" errors, guess I need to get them translated or something.

Comment: check on the logs that mention your wifi ssid/hardware vendor name/NetworkManager